# Have multiple monitors, primary display leaks onto secondary

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have 2 displays of different resolutions. My primary is 1366x768, and my secondary is 1440x900.

My primary monitor, when set to its native resolution will leak onto my secondary display by 1 row. It's impossible to show in a screenshot. I have experienced this in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 using both the default display drivers and proprietary. No change. The only workaround that I have currently is to lower the resolution on my primary.

Has anybody else experienced this issue, or is capable of reproducing it?

As always, more information will be provided when asked.

**EDIT** Output from `xrandr | grep -w connected`

```
eDP connected primary 1366x768+0+247 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
HDMI-0 connected 1440x900+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `xrandr | grep -w connected`?

Comment: Updated original post. Please excuse formatting errors, my network is being uncooperative and I copied the statement from mobile.

Comment: you can try setting your display manualy with xrandr `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 1366+0` since the eDP display bleeds onto the HDMI display increasing the 1366 could move the display out of the overlap if you mess up you can use the `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 1366+0` to reset to current setting

Comment: Can you take a look at your comment again, @WooJoo ? I'm getting this error from xrandr: `failed to parse '1366+0' as a position`

Actually, nevermind. Looking at the `--help`, the `+` should be `x`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it by adding 2 pixels to the width. See updated original post.

Comment: @skeeter_mcbee you will need to apply this change on every login.
To do this you can add the command you used to your .xprofile in your home directory. your case `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 1368x0`

Comment: @skeeter_mcbee You can add that as your own answer if you want as well just to help show that you solved the problem you were having.  You might want to remove the [Fixed] from the end of your title as well. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the fix was to adjust the position of the second monitor through `xrandr`. Adjusting the position by one pixel did not help, so I adjusted it by 2 and it works just fine. I used the following command:

`sudo xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 1368x0`

And then creating a file in my home directory called `.xprofile` and reentering the command; so it will set the position every time I log in.

Comment: If you don't like to deal with correct flags to xrandr then an alternative is the frontend to xrandr called arandr. See more details at https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/