# Can't move windows between screens with hotkey after adjusting monitor position with xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I had this problem: [Have multiple monitors, primary display leaks onto secondary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870023/have-multiple-monitors-primary-display-leaks-onto-secondary). The solution did work, I moved one of the screens by 2 pixels and the leak was gone. However, the hotkey for moving windows between screens (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>) stopped working, and I can only do it manually. Here's the output for `$ xrandr -q`.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3288 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+1368+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1366x768 (0x46) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1366 start 1436 end 1579 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  774 total  798           clock  59.79Hz
  1024x768 (0x47) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x48) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x49) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4a) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x4b) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x4c) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x4d) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NVIDIA drivers, this is PROBABLY the solution for you.  This issue was DRIVING ME NUTS. Whats worse is on my Debian 10 I was unable to log in using Wayland, unable to set fractional scaling using all the tweaks, etc.

So, i found out that by setting the scale value in xrandr, it was changing what 'NVIDIA thought where(location) the screens were layed out. I found the solution was to run open nvidia-settings, run your xrandr command (like below) - then drag your screens in nvidia settings until they are lined up correctly and hit apply.

SWEET, I can once again use my keyboard shortcuts to move windows between my 3 monitors (1080p, 4k, 1080p)

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --scale 0.7x0.7
```

[image]